# Module gaurds in Pact

Tags: pact-lang

With module gaurds, is it possible to `insert` to a table but not add a `read` function within that defined module that sits on a public chain (chainweb)...then subsequently define a module on scalableBFT (private chain) that allows an account defined on the permissioned network to read from the table sitting on the public chain? Possibly a privacy preserving method?